# Why isn't my site proper on IE but fine on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

have a look at my site : http://www.searchr.us.

Its loading fine with all the effects in FF and Chrome but not in IE ..Whats the problem ?

You can also have a look at my CSS : http://www.searchr.us/css/style.css

Please tell me what the problem is.

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific when you post questions. No one is going to check through all of your code and tell you how to fix it all so pick a few particular issues and put some actual detail in your questions.

Comment: Well,The prob is I don't know where I'm going wrong :D

Comment: one of the reasons for your page alignment issues is not having doctype. for sure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have no Doctype, therefore you are entering [Quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) in which browsers treat the code as "Rubbish from beyond the dawn of standards" and engage in deliberate misinterpretation of the specifications. IE deviates from the standard the most (going quite a long way towards emulating IE 5.x).

Comment: So what is that i have to do ? Please tell me which Doctype i have to add ?

Comment: That depends on which version of HTML you are using. HTML 4.01 Strict is generally a safe choice. Don't forget to validate … http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: in most cases, adding the following line to the top of your code will do the trick: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @Spudley — but that means validating against a moving target using tools which aren't as mature as DTD valdidators. I would treat HTML 5 as something to be selected with care, and not the default option.

Comment: @David Dorward - as long as it gets him out of Quirksmode, it solves the problem.

Comment: @David Dorward, disagree. I would use <!DOCTYPE html> and then you probably won't have to change it again for about 10 years or possibly ever. Using an older doctype, will mean using new features such as canvas will be automatically invalid, which is not much use if you're building a modern website.

Comment: @davidbuttar - that's what I said (see my first comment)

Comment: Oh sorry I meant @David Dorward.

Comment: Changing the Doctype should be a simple template change. This should be a trivial matter from a technical perspective. A website does not need to use Canvas to be modern.

Comment: That's just one example, there is also, custome data-* attributes, semantic improvements (header, footer, nav, menu etc), new form types, aria enhansements, audio/video tags and inline svg. So I would argue that if you are not using html 5 you are NOT looking to make a modern web application.

Comment: Most of those are things that need to be used with a lot of care (new block elements, for example, will be horribly broken with depending on a JavaScript shim in IE), or have plenty of alternatives (data- attributes being a case in point). You don't need any of them to create a modern web application.

Answer (score 1):

1) declare your [**doctype**](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)
2) [**Reset styles**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) helps a lot for x-browser stuff. (although if you already have your styles laid out it would probably be more of a headache than it's worth)
3) Isolate any functionality that is breaking in IE in an *effort* to [**debug**](http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-techniques-in-ie-6/) any IE specific JS that is not supported.  Also, I just found out [**NetBeans**](http://netbeans.org/) has AMAZING support for JS.  You can even test browser compatibility on a line-by-line basis.

Also, your question would be more answerable if you provided more specific details and did a little bit of debugging in an effort to isolate your problem.  `X-browser` (ex: coding for every other browser... than IE) is painful enough.

Answer (score 0):

IE is not the best browser when it comes to implementing standards. What you're experiencing is the something that probably causes a lot of premature balding in web development.

Comment: @5416339 - It's not helpful to your problem anyway.

Comment: Meant to do a commment...my bad

Comment: Then just delete the answer and repost as comment? :)

Comment: It's just a joke, lighten up.